# Tropical Plant Identification

Tags: species-identification

[image]After searching extensively I have been unable to find a name for this plant. It was found growing in the Eden Project Tropical biome in the UK. The flowers were approximately 7-8 cm across.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Beautiful photo. I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Leaf shape often helps identifying plants. Do you remember how the leaves looked like, or do you have photos where they appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to closely resemble the shape of the "Golden Chalice Vine" (*Solandara Maxima*). Although they are a more yellow color and their leaves fold outward rather than inward, it is entirely possible that the flowers you found were still in the process of fully blooming.

I also found a it growing in the Eden Project Biome you mentioned, here is the link to the plant page on their website: http://www.edenproject.com/learn/for-everyone/plant-profiles/golden-chalice-vine

And for some more pictures and information: https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/SOLANDRA_GRANDIFLORA.htm

Hope this is the plant!

Comment: The Solandra you show doesn't seem to have the thick part on the "leaves" (wich are technically petals and / or sepals) we see on the photo taken by the OP.

Comment: Hi Bli, unfortunately I do not have a photo of the leaves. It was a spur of the moment shot due to its location (being on the side of some busy stairs). On future trips I must remember to photograph leaves as well as the flowers of those plant I am not familiar with. Although I can see a similarity with the Solandra maxima that Johnny linked me to, I do agree with you in that the thick bands of green on the petals to seem to be absent in any photos I can find of it online. Thanks very much for taking the time to help me identify this, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks so much for going to the trouble that you have in helping me identify this plant. I certainly think we are on the right track with Solandra though as I remember the flowers were somewhat smaller than those described in any online site and the thick green bands I witnessed on the photo I posted also seem to be absent. Can I ask whereabouts in the dome you saw it growing? I found this one on the right side of the stairs going down from the viewing platform. If I was still in that part of the country I would go back to get more detail - leaves, growth habit etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was that I found on the Eden Project Website :P. Apologies. I agree that the flowers are larger than what you described seeing, which is why I thought it might not have been fully formed yet, but I'm no botanist so I can't say much about it, but glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

After continuing to search I have located the name of this plant. It is Ipomoea alba or 'Tropical white morning glory'. 
On locating the area of the Biome on a map where I had found it, I could conclude it grew in tropical and sub-tropical areas of South America and north of there. This narrowed down the search somewhat.
Thanks again to all involved for helping to identify!

Comment: Apparently similar to "moon vine" an ipomoea of the US that opens in the evening.